# How can I get more than 200 results from Google Reader's OAuth API?

Tags: oauth, google-reader

I can get up to 200 unread items using this:

> http://www.google.com/reader/api/0/stream/contents/user/-/state/com.google/reading-list?n=200&xt=user/-/state/com.google/read

But, **how can I get the next 200?**

(the xt parameter excludes read items)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need to extract the `continuation` attribute in the response and then make another request with that value as a `c` query parameter (see http://code.google.com/p/google-reader-api/wiki/ApiStreamContents for details).

Comment: Thanks.  It looks like Google Reader now allows up to 1000 items so this is less of an issue now.  But if I have to go deeper, it's helpful to know how.